# Div Inner Text Selection using Javascript (with keyboard?)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My goal is to create a caret browsing extension in google chrome.  I have hit a wall with text selection.  I've found that I can select the contents of a div:

```
range = document.createRange();
referenceNode = document.getElementsByTagName("div").item(0);
range.selectNode(referenceNode);
```

I can also select child elements using `range.setStart(referenceNode,offest)` and `range.setEnd(referenceNode,offset)` where offset is the number of child nodes to skip/include in the selection.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to select individual characters within a div.  This behavior is, ofcourse, available for textareas and input textfields.  I'm hoping for a legit javascript solution that I missed, but a hack-around suggestion using DOM manipulation of one form or another is also acceptable.

It is important that the solution allow for caret-browsing like behavior.  For example, given the starting position as an offset from some location, and the ending position as an offset from the same location, display the selection *in position* on the screen and allow for copying the selection.

Thank you for your time.

Best Regards,
Lotus

Comment: Check out rangy: http://code.google.com/p/rangy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is hack or not but it is working.
(I just made that) Try demo: http://derek1906.site50.net/experiment/selection/

You can put a `<span></span>` around the individual characters that you want to select and then you just select the `<span>` and Wa-la, you selected the words you want!

Comment: Thank you.  I think this might be useful.  I could insert a span at the location of the "cursor", and then as the cursor moves I can move characters following the span into the span to simulate selection.  Hmm Thank you :)